# How use replace function to convert all elements of an arraylist object in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to convert items of an arrylist object, in my dsl groovy script given by :

```
branches = ['test/1.2.0', 'test1/1.4.0']
```

And I want to get as result :

```
branches = ['test_1.2.0', 'test1_1.4.0']
```

I tried these methods :

```
branches = branches.each {
    def branchName = it
    branchName = branchName.replaceAll('/','_')
}
```

and

```
branches = branches.each {
    it -> it.replaceAll('//','_')
}
```

But, I get the same thing after doing println :

my result was :

```
branches = ['test/1.2.0', 'test1/1.4.0']
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `each` is a no-op for what you are after. Use `collect` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the spread (*) operator for this, check the documentation here: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/:

```
branches = ['test/1.2.0', 'test1/1.4.0']
branches = branches*.replace('/', '_')
println branches
```